# Installation Failed: pipenv install google-ads (TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object)

Tags: python, google-ads-api, pipenv

`pipenv install google-ads` produces an error:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
This is likely caused by a bug in google-ads. Report this to its maintainers.
✘ Installation Failed
```

This is the whole thing:

```
% pipenv install google-ads
Creating a virtualenv for this project...
Pipfile: /Users/ralf/code/test_snippets/20-12-10_google_ads/Pipfile
Using /usr/local/bin/python3.9 (3.9.0) to create virtualenv...
⠦ Creating virtual environment...created virtual environment CPython3.9.0.final.0-64 in 325ms
  creator CPython3Posix(dest=/Users/ralf/.local/share/virtualenvs/20-12-10_google_ads-S7vGVfKj, clear=False, global=False)
  seeder FromAppData(download=False, pip=bundle, setuptools=bundle, wheel=bundle, via=copy, app_data_dir=/Users/ralf/Library/Application Support/virtualenv)
    added seed packages: pip==20.2.4, setuptools==50.3.2, wheel==0.35.1
  activators BashActivator,CShellActivator,FishActivator,PowerShellActivator,PythonActivator,XonshActivator

✔ Successfully created virtual environment! 
Virtualenv location: /Users/ralf/.local/share/virtualenvs/20-12-10_google_ads-S7vGVfKj
Installing google-ads...
Error:  An error occurred while installing google-ads!
Error text: Processing /Users/ralf/Library/Caches/pipenv/wheels/0a/09/22/d4a45ac4200d9c68a5215e554d4181b51af2c01b4f16232b5c/google_ads-8.0.0-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting googleapis-common-protos<2.0.0,>=1.5.8
  Using cached googleapis_common_protos-1.52.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (100 kB)
Collecting google-auth-oauthlib<1.0.0,>=0.3.0
  Using cached google_auth_oauthlib-0.4.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (18 kB)
Collecting protobuf<4.0.0,>=3.13.0
  Using cached protobuf-3.14.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (173 kB)
Collecting google-api-core<2.0.0,>=1.14.0
  Using cached google_api_core-1.23.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (91 kB)
Processing /Users/ralf/Library/Caches/pipenv/wheels/69/60/81/5cd74b8ee068fbe9e04ca0d53148f28f5c6e2c5b177d5dd622/PyYAML-5.3.1-cp39-cp39-macosx_11_0_x86_64.whl
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: setuptools>=40.3.0 in /Users/ralf/.local/share/virtualenvs/20-12-10_google_ads-S7vGVfKj/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from google-ads->-r /var/folders/nc/s6kd50kj3gdg81vhy9qwddkw0000gn/T/pipenv-p0t2erav-requirements/pipenv-xefzspt6-requirement.txt (line 1)) (50.3.2)
Collecting grpcio<2.0.0,>=1.33.2
  Using cached grpcio-1.34.0.tar.gz (21.0 MB)

    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /Users/ralf/.local/share/virtualenvs/20-12-10_google_ads-S7vGVfKj/bin/python -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/nc/s6kd50kj3gdg81vhy9qwddkw0000gn/T/pip-install-woj2xbsv/grpcio/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/nc/s6kd50kj3gdg81vhy9qwddkw0000gn/T/pip-install-woj2xbsv/grpcio/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /private/var/folders/nc/s6kd50kj3gdg81vhy9qwddkw0000gn/T/pip-pip-egg-info-d7h_fmnt
         cwd: /private/var/folders/nc/s6kd50kj3gdg81vhy9qwddkw0000gn/T/pip-install-woj2xbsv/grpcio/
    Complete output (9 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/nc/s6kd50kj3gdg81vhy9qwddkw0000gn/T/pip-install-woj2xbsv/grpcio/setup.py", line 359, in <module>
        if mac_target and (pkg_resources.parse_version(mac_target) <
      File "/Users/ralf/.local/share/virtualenvs/20-12-10_google_ads-S7vGVfKj/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 113, in parse_version
        return packaging.version.Version(v)
      File "/Users/ralf/.local/share/virtualenvs/20-12-10_google_ads-S7vGVfKj/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pkg_resources/_vendor/packaging/version.py", line 275, in __init__
        match = self._regex.search(version)
    TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.

This is likely caused by a bug in google-ads. Report this to its maintainers.
✘ Installation Failed
```

I do not know much about pipenv, I am just using it – so far without any problems. Now I started from scratch and ran `brew update`, `brew outdated` and `brew upgrade` before.

How do I report that to its maintainers best, and what does "its" mean, Google Ads or Pipenv? Is there something else I could do?

**Update:**

Following [tai271828's advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65290795/13520223) here are some further information about the system I am using:

- I just updated to `Mac OS 11.1 (20C69)` (so it probably was 11.01 before)
- `python --version` --> `Python 2.7.16`
- `which python` --> `/usr/bin/python`
- `which python3` --> `/usr/local/bin/python3`
- `python3 --version` --> `Python 3.9.0`
- `which pipenv` --> `/usr/local/bin/pipenv`
- `which pip` --> `/usr/local/bin/pip`
- `which pip3` --> `/usr/local/bin/pip3`

I used homebrew to install Python 3 and then `pip3 install pipenv`.

**Update 2:**

With simply `pip` (instead of `pipenv`) I first ran into the same error, but after **updating pip**, it worked fine. This was my input:

```
python3 -m venv venv
source venv/bin/activate
pip install --upgrade pip
pip install google-ads
```

**Update 3:**

I tried to follow [tai271828's advise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65246529/installation-failed-pipenv-install-google-ads-typeerror-expected-string-or-by#comment115480596_65246529), to update my pip in my pipenv env prior to installing the google-ads package. These were my commands:

```
pipenv --rm
pipenv shell
pip insall --upgrade pip
exit
pipenv install google-ads
```

The error message still looks similar:

```
Installing google-ads...
Adding google-ads to Pipfile's [packages]...
✔ Installation Succeeded 
Pipfile.lock (16c839) out of date, updating to (f55075)...
Locking [dev-packages] dependencies...
Locking [packages] dependencies...
Building requirements...
Resolving dependencies...
✘ Locking Failed! 
ERROR:pip.subprocessor:Command errored out with exit status 1:
 command: /Users/ralf/.local/share/virtualenvs/20-12-10_google_ads-S7vGVfKj/bin/python -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/nc/s6kd50kj3gdg81vhy9qwddkw0000gn/T/pip-resolver-p0oskrkm/grpcio/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/nc/s6kd50kj3gdg81vhy9qwddkw0000gn/T/pip-resolver-p0oskrkm/grpcio/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /private/var/folders/nc/s6kd50kj3gdg81vhy9qwddkw0000gn/T/pip-resolver-p0oskrkm/grpcio/pip-egg-info
     cwd: /private/var/folders/nc/s6kd50kj3gdg81vhy9qwddkw0000gn/T/pip-resolver-p0oskrkm/grpcio/
Complete output (9 lines):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/private/var/folders/nc/s6kd50kj3gdg81vhy9qwddkw0000gn/T/pip-resolver-p0oskrkm/grpcio/setup.py", line 359, in <module>
    if mac_target and (pkg_resources.parse_version(mac_target) <
  File "/Users/ralf/.local/share/virtualenvs/20-12-10_google_ads-S7vGVfKj/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 113, in parse_version
    return packaging.version.Version(v)
  File "/Users/ralf/.local/share/virtualenvs/20-12-10_google_ads-S7vGVfKj/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pkg_resources/_vendor/packaging/version.py", line 275, in __init__
    match = self._regex.search(version)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
----------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 764, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 758, in main
    _main(parsed.pre, parsed.clear, parsed.verbose, parsed.system, parsed.write,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 741, in _main
    resolve_packages(pre, clear, verbose, system, write, requirements_dir, packages, dev)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 702, in resolve_packages
    results, resolver = resolve(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 684, in resolve
    return resolve_deps(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pipenv/utils.py", line 1395, in resolve_deps
    results, hashes, markers_lookup, resolver, skipped = actually_resolve_deps(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pipenv/utils.py", line 1108, in actually_resolve_deps
    resolver.resolve()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pipenv/utils.py", line 823, in resolve
    results = self.resolver.resolve(max_rounds=environments.PIPENV_MAX_ROUNDS)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pipenv/patched/piptools/resolver.py", line 180, in resolve
    has_changed, best_matches = self._resolve_one_round()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pipenv/patched/piptools/resolver.py", line 268, in _resolve_one_round
    their_constraints.extend(self._iter_dependencies(best_match))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pipenv/patched/piptools/resolver.py", line 383, in _iter_dependencies
    dependencies = self.repository.get_dependencies(ireq)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pipenv/patched/piptools/repositories/pypi.py", line 229, in get_dependencies
    legacy_results = self.get_legacy_dependencies(ireq)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pipenv/patched/piptools/repositories/pypi.py", line 350, in get_legacy_dependencies
    results, ireq = self.resolve_reqs(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pipenv/patched/piptools/repositories/pypi.py", line 306, in resolve_reqs
    results = resolver._resolve_one(reqset, ireq)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pipenv/patched/notpip/_internal/legacy_resolve.py", line 339, in _resolve_one
    abstract_dist = self._get_abstract_dist_for(req_to_install)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pipenv/patched/notpip/_internal/legacy_resolve.py", line 287, in _get_abstract_dist_for
    abstract_dist = self.preparer.prepare_linked_requirement(req)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pipenv/patched/notpip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 508, in prepare_linked_requirement
    abstract_dist = _get_prepared_distribution(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pipenv/patched/notpip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 95, in _get_prepared_distribution
    abstract_dist.prepare_distribution_metadata(finder, build_isolation)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pipenv/patched/notpip/_internal/distributions/sdist.py", line 40, in prepare_distribution_metadata
    self.req.prepare_metadata()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pipenv/patched/notpip/_internal/req/req_install.py", line 564, in prepare_metadata
    self.metadata_directory = self._generate_metadata()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pipenv/patched/notpip/_internal/req/req_install.py", line 538, in _generate_metadata
    return generate_metadata_legacy(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pipenv/patched/notpip/_internal/operations/build/metadata_legacy.py", line 115, in generate_metadata
    call_subprocess(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pipenv/patched/notpip/_internal/utils/subprocess.py", line 242, in call_subprocess
    raise InstallationError(exc_msg)
pipenv.patched.notpip._internal.exceptions.InstallationError: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

By the way: I upgraded to Python 3.9.1 meanwhile.

Comment: In your case, `pip` works fine because it is running in system-wise environment with the default python (python 2.7.16) in your macOS. It is that not useful information for your pipenv virtual environment built on top of python 3.9, because the env of python 2 and 3 may differ a lot.

Comment: Besides, I just tried python 3.9 pipenv installation of google-ads. It works well (ubuntu-mate 18.04) for your reference.

Comment: Would you mind to `pipenv shell` to get in the virtual environment you created (with python 3.9) and then have a look of the output of `python setup.py egg_info` suggested by the error message?

Comment: Thanks for your further comments. I found out that with simply "pip", it worked after updating it, meaning pip itself (see "Update 2" above).

Comment: Sounds stupid, but I do not find the log pip/pipenv is writing on my Mac, even after something like `pip install google-ads --log mylogifle`.

Comment: Interesting, if the upgraded pip does help, two tips for your reference in the future. 1. Use `which pip` to confirm it is the pip in your python3 venv (and not using `/usr/local/bin/pip` for system-wise python2). 2. if you want to use pipenv again, you may want to update your pip in your pipenv env prior to installing google-ads package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It took me a while to figure that out, but it seems to be a problem of `pipenv` under `Python 3.9` (or 3.9.1) in conjunction with the `google-ads` Module.

My solution:

1. downgrading to `Python 3.8.6` (For me as rookie it was a struggle, just in case you are interested in that: [Switching Python version (3.9 → 3.8) installed by Homebrew](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65337641/switching-python-version-3-9-%E2%86%92-3-8-installed-by-homebrew))
2. Upgrading `pip` inside pipenv

I did this like that:

```
pipenv shell
pip install --upgrade pip
exit
```

Then it finally worked:

```
% pipenv install google-ads
Installing google-ads...
Adding google-ads to Pipfile's [packages]...
✔ Installation Succeeded 
Pipfile.lock not found, creating...
Locking [dev-packages] dependencies...
Locking [packages] dependencies...
Building requirements...
Resolving dependencies...
✔ Success! 
Updated Pipfile.lock (aba984)!
Installing dependencies from Pipfile.lock (aba984)...
     ▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉ 0/0 — 00:00:00
To activate this project's virtualenv, run pipenv shell.
Alternatively, run a command inside the virtualenv with pipenv run.
```

Hurray!

Comment: I had similar kind of "setup" and upgrading pip inside the pipenv helped me!

Comment: `~/.virtualenvs/MYENVNAME/bin/python3.8 -m pip install --upgrade pip` (as prompted at the bottom of the failure) did the trick for me :)

Answer (score 1):

1. The statement "This is likely caused by a bug in google-ads. Report this to its maintainers." is raised by pipenv. It means "please do not report the issue to pipenv development team".
2. It seems that you are running the command on a mac/OSX. Besides, it seems that your pipenv is installed by brew. If both of the statements are right, then it is very likely that you are mixing your system-wise pip and local-installed pipenv (by brew). This is a very frequent mistake raised by people who are not familiar with how python package management works.

   1. Thus, the first suggestion to find a solution, is to elaborate the python package management related information on your system (mac/OSX) as much as possible. For example, the output message of `python --version`, `which python`, `which pip`, and `which pipenv` is usually help.
   2. If you want to use brew to manage packages for you, make sure every step you used to install pipenv and your target package does not mix your system-wise python environment and your local(managed by brew or a python virtual environment) when trying to figure out the issue and finding a solution. For example, make sure you are starting your operation from a "clean" and just-re-spawned terminal. If you want to use brew, make sure you are controlling everything via brew. It will be a bad idea to activate a customized python virtual environment (e.g. conda environment) and then using brew.