# Does simply uninstalling Python 3.9 and installing Python 3.8 again with Homebrew work?

Tags: python, homebrew

I used Python 3.8.6, installed via Homebrew on my Mac (Mac OS 11.1), and everything was fine. After upgrading Python to 3.9 (and later 3.9.1) with Homebrew, there is an [issue with one of the moduls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65246529/installation-failed-pipenv-install-google-ads-typeerror-expected-string-or-by) which might be caused by that and I want to go back.

Trouble with Python versions seems to be a quite common and there are tons of articles etc. about that, but so far nothing worked for me. [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) is often recommended, but actually I do not need the 3.9 version at the moment and did not want to introduce another layer of complexity.

I found a [tempting thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64362772/switching-python-version-installed-by-homebrew) for a similar situation but following these advices confused somehow my `pipenv` which somehow still sticks to Python 3.9. (Update: meanwhile I could [solve that problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65337641/switching-python-version-3-9-%E2%86%92-3-8-installed-by-homebrew/65337642#65337642)).

Anyway, my idea was to simply run `brew uninstall python` and then `brew install python@3.8` (or however addressing the 3.8 version works).

If I try so, there is a warning:

```
 % brew uninstall python
Error: Refusing to uninstall /usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.1
because it is required by ffmpeg, glib, gobject-introspection, libass and libxml2, which are currently installed.
You can override this and force removal with:
  brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies python
```

**Is it a good idea to ignore the dependencies?** I assume everything will get fixed via installing the 3.8 version later, or at least `brew doctor` would somehow help me if something will go wrong by that.

By the way: how exactly is the brew command for installing Python 3.8?

Comment: Did you do it and did it work?